# Which cloud database companies let you store data directly from a mobile client with JSON?

Tags: iphone, database, json, mobile

The goal is to store data in a hosted database without touching our servers.

If multiple companies offer this, what are the pros/cons of each? What is your experience with these services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is an amazing company to do what you are looking for with a really nice and easy to use api.  Check out [parse.com](http://www.parse.com)

They have a ton of info there to get you started and they are free if you use less than 1 million api calls a month last time i checked.  I have used them several times for personal projects with everything from storing data to sending push notifications.  I believe their service is backed by Amazon cloud servers which are pretty reliable.